# Outlook Integration - New Case - From Address

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

I have added the add-in Salesforce in Outlook, using it to create new Case via a Publisher Action.

In the new Case, I am getting only the Subject and Email body in the Case Subject/Description fields.

How to get the From Address in the email into the new Case via this add-in [Outlook Integration]?
Any similar use case?

[image]